# What does “Nom marital” mean?

Tags: vocabulaire

What does **nom marital** mean? Is it related to marital status?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is indeed related to your marital status. It is a woman's "married name". It refers to the name she uses after her marriage, if she uses her husband's name. It is the opposite of her "maiden name", called *nom de jeune fille* in French, which is to say the name she was using before her marriage.

For example, if Mary O'Neil marries John Smith and goes by the name Mary Smith or Mary O'Neil Smith, her *nom marital* would be Mary Smith or Mary O'Neil Smith, and her *nom de jeune fille* would be Mary O'Neil.

Comment: The official denomination of _nom de jeune fille_ or _nom de naissance_ is _nom patronymique_. Only this one has a legal status.

Answer (score 5):

*Nom marital* is married name, i.e. a surname taken upon marriage, usually the surname of the spouse.

*Nom de jeune fille* or *nom de naissance* is maiden name, i.e. a women's original surname.

In France, women traditionally took their husband's name when they marry; the practice has become less common nowadays. Most official forms have a line for *Nom* or *Nom de famille*, which is the only “legal” surname (enter your maiden name), and a line for *Nom marital*. Some forms have *Nom* and *Nom de naissance*, in which case *nom* should be the usual surname (which can be spouse's name), and *nom de naissance* is the official surname.